# Fractional sobolev spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, laplacian

On the whole space $\mathbb R^d$, the fractional Sobolev space 
$H_s(\mathbb R^d)$ of order $s\in \mathbb R$ can be defined as the subspace of tempered distributions $T$ such that $\mathcal F T \in L^2(\mathbb R^d)$ and $|\cdot |^{2s} \mathcal F T(\cdot) \in L^2(\mathbb R^d)$.

If $D$ is a smooth bounded domain in $\mathbb R^d$, there exists an orthonormal basis $(\Phi_k)$ of $L^2(D)$, where $\Phi_k$ is an eigenfunction of $-\Delta$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions with eigenvalue $\lambda_k$. For any $s\geq 0$, we can define the Hilbert space $H_s(D)$ to be the space of functions $f\in L^2(D)$ such that 
$$\sum_{k\geq 1} |\langle f , \Phi_k \rangle |^2 (1+\lambda_k)^s <+\infty$$ 
For any $s>0$ we define $H_{-s}(D)$ to be the topological dual of $H_s(D)$.

My question is: Is there a relation between $H_s(\mathbb R^d)$ and $H_s(D)$. For instance do we have $H_s(\mathbb R^d)\subset H_s(D)$, where the embedding is continuous?

Comment: It is clear what one wants to do for integer $s\ge 0$: $H_s(D)$ needs to be the space of functions with $s$ derivatives in $L^2$, with norm determined by the $L^2$ norms of those derivatives. If you can check that your definition via the Laplacian is equivalent to this (which, if true, should be in the literature), then the restriction maps $H_s(\mathbb R^d)\to H_s(D)$ are obviously continuous for $s=0,1,\ldots$, and the rest should follow by interpolation.

Comment: Thank you for the edit and for the indication, I will look into that!